# zsh - command not found for written script

Tags: bash, macos, zsh, iterm2, zshrc

I am using mac and I have a script file `print_hello`:

```
#!/bin/bash
echo hello
```

and if I run it directly from directory with `./print_hello` command and zsh terminal it will properly print hello. I would like to add it as a global command, so then writing `print_hello` in terminal should print me "hello". but the thing I am getting is:

```
zsh: command not found: print_hello
```

The path is right ( I edited it in `.zshrc`). The file has the proper permissions (I used `chmod 755 print_hello`):

```
➜ ~ echo $PATH
/Users/mateusz/bin:/usr/local/bin:/Users/mateusz/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/Library/GE/bin:~/scripts
```

and the `print_hello` file is in `~/scripts`

The only way I can run the script is directly from its directory. What should I do? I added some aliases in `.zshrc` and they are working, so why are executable scripts are not working?

Comment: Tried exactly your scenario, using `zsh` on Mac, and it works for me.

Comment: Unlikely to be related, but why do you have separate `~/bin` and `~/scripts` directories, instead of just using `~/bin`?

Comment: Have you tryied expanding `~` before adding to PATH, ie. `export PATH=$PATH:$HOME/scripts` ?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It is strange, but the thing that helped me was replacing

```
~/scripts
```

with

```
$HOME/scripts
```

in .zhrc file

Comment: Seems like env param $HOME got different path? Not sure